# image height displays 0, requestAnimationFrame(); javascript html5 game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programming a game

I have the next settings:

**HTML** `game.html`

```
      <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>

             <script src="game.js"></script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** `game.js`

```
var document;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//load images
var pipeNorth = new Image();
pipeNorth.src = "images/pipeNorth.png";


function draw(){

    /*code */
    alert(pipeNorth.height);


        requestAnimationFrame(draw);

        }

    draw();
```

**PROBLEM**

If I set an alert displaying the image height, it shows `0` during the first two  or three alerts, then it starts showing the real height.

Why does this happen? How do I fix this? I think it means the image is not fully loaded when the game begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience this happens because the document rendering takes some time. My technique for this case is a time delay:

```
function draw(){
    var delay = 200;//Your delay in milliseconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        /*code */
        alert(pipeNorth.height);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    },delay);
}
```

Is it usable for you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right the image is not fully loaded when the game begins.to fix this you simply have to use the "load" event :

```js
var document;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//load images
var pipeNorth = new Image();
pipeNorth.src = "images/pipeNorth.png";


function draw(){

    /*code */
    alert(pipeNorth.height);


        requestAnimationFrame(draw);

 }


pipeNorth.addEventListener("load",function(){
//this function will execute when the image is fully loaded
draw();
});
```

Comment: I just cant figure out how to attach your code to mine.